# How to use * in python

Tags: python

Why func worked and func2 not worked? and how it fixes? Please help me ...

```
def func(name):
    return name*10
a = func("Jack")
print (a)

#==============================================#

count = input("EnterTheNum =  ")
def func2(name2):
    return name2*count
b = func2("Max")
print (b)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Did you try to google the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your `input` in `int()` function to cast it to integer

```
count = int(input('Enter the num = '))
```

`input` method returns a string by default